# How can i add a array to a matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

let say I have this array :

```
import numpy as np
a = [[]]
b = np.array([1,2,3])
c = np.array([7,8,9])
```

How can I tell to Python I want a like this :

```
a = [[1,2,3],[7,8,9]]
```

Thank you !

Comment: `a=[b,c]` isn't enough?

Comment: @SangbokLee that would result in a list.

Comment: do you want a numpy matrix or a list of lists? or an array of arrays?